# How to use the section sign § as a comment delimiter in listings?

Tags: listings, listingsutf8

I tried to define a custom language in listingsutf8 (The file's inputenc is utf8), which uses the section sign § as comment delimiter. I defined the language like this (I'll only paste the important parts, not keywords and stuff):

```
\lstdefinelanguage{Simple}{
     morecomment=[l]{§},
     morecomment=[n]{§(}{§)}
}
```

I used it like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Simple]
    Test § Test
\end{lstlisting}
```

The problem is, that the section sign causes the following error when used inside a listing:
`Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\lst@EC� (U+9E67)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. Test §`

I tried masking the character with the literate option in the language definition, but then the comments are no longer recognized as comments.

```
\lstdefinelanguage{Simple}{
    morecomment=[l]{§},
    morecomment=[n]{§(}{§)},
    literate={§}{\S}{1}
}
```

I also tried defining the unicode character 9E67 to be the section sign using `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{9E67}{\S}`, but this didn't work either.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{0.9,0.4,0}
\definecolor{lorange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
\definecolor{dblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.4}
\definecolor{dgreen}{rgb}{0,0.3,0}
\definecolor{dpurple}{rgb}{0.4,0,0.4}

\lstdefinelanguage{Simple}{
    morekeywords={void, boolean, bool, int, float, include, from, as, direct, if, while, do, for, loop, switch, else, case, break, continue, return, test, step, in},
    sensitive=true,
    morecomment=[l]{§},
    morecomment=[n]{§(}{§)},
    morecomment=[n][\color{lorange}\itshape]{§\{}{§\}},
    morecomment=[n]{§[}{§]},
    morecomment=[n]{§<}{§>},
    morestring=[b]{"},
    morestring=[b][numberstyle]{'}
}

\lstdefinestyle{simple}{
    language=Simple,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\mdseries,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{dpurple},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{orange},
    identifierstyle=\color{dgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{dblue},
    numberstyle=\itshape\color{dblue},
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=l,
    columns=flexible
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=Simple]

§{
§ Multi line comment
§}
+ main():
    § Single line comment
    return 0
.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Make a complete example that we can use for tests. Showing only snippets makes it harder for other to help you.

Comment: I think it needs to be a single token and § is two tokens to pdftex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, no comments can be more than one token, e.g. `morecomment=[l]{/*} ` is allowed. But I have no idea how literate and listingsutf8 would affect an utf8 character as comment char.

Comment: This is an example file that throws the error I mentioned:
http://pastebin.com/CDCswFNb

Furthermore, I recognized it throws a different error when I remove the `columns=flexible` part in the style, namely this one:
`Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\lst@FillFixed@ (U+5A8)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. §{` Maybe there's a problem with that option?

Comment: Don't put your code behind a temporary link like pastebin. Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Do you have the option of using a UTF-8 engine? Your document works fine using regular `listings` and XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, and loading `fontspec` instead of `inputenc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `listingsutf8` requires the listing in a separate file, because then the package can catch the file, convert it to the specified 8-bit encoding and passes the result to package `listings`. Therefore, `listings` will see the 8-bit encoding and the style definition must follow this encoding. Since the TeX document is encoded in UTF-8, most editors will have problems with differently encoded characters. But TeX has a ASCII method for specifying characters using `^^` with the two digit hex number. `§` can be specified with `^^a7`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{0.9,0.4,0}
\definecolor{lorange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
\definecolor{dblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.4}
\definecolor{dgreen}{rgb}{0,0.3,0}
\definecolor{dpurple}{rgb}{0.4,0,0.4}

\lstdefinelanguage{Simple}{
    morekeywords={void, boolean, bool, int, float, include, from,
      as, direct, if, while, do, for, loop, switch, else, case,
      break, continue, return, test, step, in},
    sensitive=true,
    morecomment=[l]{^^a7},
    morecomment=[n]{^^a7(}{^^a7)},
    morecomment=[n][\color{lorange}\itshape]{^^a7\{}{^^a7\}},
    morecomment=[n][\color{lorange}\itshape]{^^a7\{}{^^a7\}},
    morecomment=[n]{^^a7[}{^^a7]},
    morecomment=[n]{^^a7<}{^^a7>},
    morestring=[b]{"},
    morestring=[b][numberstyle]{'}
}

\lstdefinestyle{simple}{
    language=Simple,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\mdseries,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{dpurple},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{orange},
    identifierstyle=\color{dgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{dblue},
    numberstyle=\itshape\color{dblue},
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=l,
    columns=flexible
}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{SimpleTest.txt}
§{
§ Multi line comment
§}
+ main():
    § Single line comment
    return 0
.
\end{filecontents*}
\lstinputlisting[
  style=Simple,
  inputencoding=utf8/latin1,
]{SimpleTest.txt}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]