# Copy/Paste from R Studio to TeXStudio: Newlines and UTF-8 Issues

Tags: texstudio, rstudio

I am seeing a difference of behavior from my Mac to my Linux machine in copy/paste from R Studio to TeXStudio. I am executing R commands in R Studio, and then I want to copy the output into TeXStudio. A typical example would be if I fit a linear model in R, find its summary output, and want to include that in my LaTeX document:

```
lmod = lm(gamble ~ sex + status + income + verbal, teengamb)
summary(lmod)
```

Now at this point, R has produced about 22 lines of output that look like this:

```
Call:
lm(formula = gamble ~ sex + status + income + verbal, data = teengamb)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-51.082 -11.320  -1.451   9.452  94.252 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  22.55565   17.19680   1.312   0.1968    
sex         -22.11833    8.21111  -2.694   0.0101 *  
status        0.05223    0.28111   0.186   0.8535    
income        4.96198    1.02539   4.839 1.79e-05 ***
verbal       -2.95949    2.17215  -1.362   0.1803    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 22.69 on 42 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5267,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4816 
F-statistic: 11.69 on 4 and 42 DF,  p-value: 1.815e-06
```

I want to simply copy/paste this into a `lstlistings` environment in TeXStudio. Here's the difference I see: when I do this on my Linux machine (running Pop!_OS 21.10), the copy/paste respects the line endings, and the formatting is exactly how I see it in R Studio. But on my Mac (running macOS Monterey 12.1), it pastes as one long line and doesn't preserve the formatting. I want to keep the formatting! How can I do that on my Mac?

My second issue is with the line

```
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

After pasting into my LaTeX document and attempting to compile, it complains as follows:

```
Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence. Signif. codes: 0 ‘*
```

Why is this happening? I thought R output was ASCII: surely ASCII would be valid UTF-8, right?

Comment: If the cut and paste is dropping line ends then that is a matter of interpretation of the clipboard by the editors at either end, and not much latex can do about it. On the mac if you paste that text into other editors (or this website) are line endings preserved, that is: is texstudio dropping them or is your R front end not adding them?

Comment: On my Mac, if I paste from R into, say, MacVim, the line endings are preserved. So it seems to me to be a TeXStudio thing.

Comment: Your signif line is certainly not ascii the quotes `‘***’` are U+2018 and U+2019, they are necessarily valid UTF-8 when posted to this site impossible to say what the original is unless you can make it available at some URL

Comment: Hmm. Well, fileformat.info confirms what you said, and also says the asterisk are plain ol' U+002A. Any idea why LaTeX is complaining, then? It should be fine! I'm inside a `lstlisting` environment, so I just want to output what I input.

Comment: oh well there you go listings can't handle utf8, see the `listingsutf8` package. listings by default will grab a byte at a time so mess up the utf8 encoding

Comment: Hmm. Looks like the `listingsutf8` file requires things to be in a separate file (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322184/how-to-use-the-section-sign-as-a-comment-delimiter-in-listings#323552), which is decidedly inconvenient. I'd rather delete the offending line than use separate files like that. It's not a particularly important line, thankfully.

Comment: Is there a setting in TeXStudio I need to change so it can handle the line endings on a Mac?

Comment: sorry I have never used texstudio

Comment: for listings you can also use the literate key as a utf workaround, see examples on this site

Comment: See [here](https://edugit.org/Teckids/team-pr/teckids-tex/-/blob/c1c544a0c46da144f38719103423006ba41fafb5/teckids2style.sty#L324) for a well-tested in-prod `literate` configuration for `listings` and UTF-8, with latin1 and some spaces and dashes and other characters (can be extended if the document needs it)